# Is this algorithm for Merge K sorted arrays in Java correct?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array, data-structures

I was being asked in an Interview to write a Java program to merge K Sorted arrays.
Something like below would be the input:

```
int[][] kSortedArrs = { {1, 5, 6, 8},
                {2, 4, 10, 12},
                {3, 7, 9, 11},
                {13, 14, 15, 16}} ;
```

I knew the solution for merging two sorted arrays, so I wrote that method (mergeSortedArrs) & used it repeatedly as a solution for this problem.
Code looks like the below:

```
    public static int[] mergeKSortedArrays(int[][] arr) {
        int[] mergedArr = new int[] {};
        for(int i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            mergedArr = mergeSortedArrs(mergedArr, arr[i]);
        }
        return mergedArr;
    }

    private static int[] mergeSortedArrs(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
        int[] arr3 = new int[arr1.length + arr2.length];
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < arr3.length; k++) {
            if (i >= arr1.length) {
                arr3[k] = arr2[j++];
                continue;
            }
            if (j >= arr2.length) {
                arr3[k] = arr1[i++];
                continue;
            }
            arr3[k] = arr1[i] <= arr2[j] ? arr1[i++] : arr2[j++];
        }
        return arr3;
    }
```

My code worked fine, at least for the test cases that were given to me.
But I want to know if this solution has any drawbacks in terms of it's correctness, because I searched on the internet but could not find a solution that is close to this solution of mine. Hence, I am a bit skeptical if I have messed up something.
Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is correct and solves the problem, but it's slow. Imagine you had `k` lists of `1` element each, your code would merge the first two, then add the third, then the fourth and so on, for a total runtime complexity of `O(k^2)`.

If you were to instead do a single pass over the array where you merge the first with the second, the third with the fourth and so on, you would end up with `k/2` sorted lists of length `2`, this runs in `O(k)`. Do this again to get `k/4` lists of length `4` and so on, until you only have one list. This runs in `O(k log k)`, which is much faster.

Comment: Thank you so much fafl for your explanation. I now understood that it can be done in a more optimal way. I have found out some posts online explaining the O(k log k) solution, I am looking into it.